# Google Chromecast subtitle not working

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I have this code

```
var englishSubtitle = new chrome.cast.media.Track(2,chrome.cast.media.TrackType.TEXT);
englishSubtitle.trackContentId = 'english.vtt';
englishSubtitle.trackContentType = 'text/vtt';
englishSubtitle.subtype = chrome.cast.media.TextTrackType.CAPTIONS;
englishSubtitle.name = 'English';
englishSubtitle.language = 'en-US';
englishSubtitle.customData = null;
var tracks = englishSubtitle;

var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(app.streamState_.manifest);
mediaInfo.contentType = app.streamState_.type;
mediaInfo.metadata = new chrome.cast.media.GenericMediaMetadata();
mediaInfo.customData = null;
mediaInfo.streamType = chrome.cast.media.StreamType.BUFFERED;
mediaInfo.textTrackStyle = new chrome.cast.media.TextTrackStyle();
mediaInfo.tracks = tracks; 
mediaInfo.metadata.metadataType = chrome.cast.media.MetadataType.GENERIC;

var activeTrackIds = [2];   

var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
request.autoplay = true;
request.currentTime = 0;
request.activeTrackIds = activeTrackIds;
session.loadMedia(request,onMediaDiscovered.bind(   this, 'loadedMedia'),  onMediaError);
```

I want to show subtitle on chromecast. When I want to set activeTracks on the request, I receive an error 
    Object {code: "session_error", description: "INVALID_PARAMS", details: Object}
The subtitle it doesn't show and the video doesn't play it at all, because of that error.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Google cast documentation => activeTrackIds

Array of number

Array of Track trackIds that should be active. If the array is not provided, the default tracks will be active. If two incompatible trackIds are provided (for example two active audio tracks) the command will fail with INVALID_PARAMETER. (https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest)

Comment: I read the documentation, but I can not understand what I am doing wrong. Because I send a single trackid, which is text

Comment: In the tutorial, subtitles subtype is `chrome.cast.media.TextTrackType.SUBTITLES`

Comment: I tryed also with SUBTITLES and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tracks` should be an array when you set

```
mediaInfo.tracks = tracks;
```

In your case, you should try

```
var tracks = [englishSubtitle];
```

and as was said earlier, use SUBTITLES instead of CAPTIONS. Finally make sure you have CORS headers present from your web server even if you are using mp4.

Answer (score 0):

`tracks` should be stored inside an array
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo#tracks
Array of non-null chrome.cast.media.Track
Array of Track objects.

```
mediaInfo.tracks = [englishSubtitle, frenchSubtitle, germanSubtitle]
```

I've created a simple javascript wrapper for the chromecast SDK:
**https://github.com/Fenny/ChromecastJS**

Might be worth to check out if you stumble upon more problems, good luck!